# how to connect two different computers in two different networks

Tags: python, sockets

this code below is working fine between two computers on the same network but it doesn't work between two computers on two different networks and i have tried to use the public IP address

clint

```
import socket               
s = socket.socket()         
port = 10000
ip=input("what is ip : ")
s.connect((ip, port))
print (s.recv(1024))
s.close
```

server

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
ip=socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
print (ip)
port = 10000           
s.bind((ip, port))       
s.listen(1)                 
while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print ('Got connection from', addr)
        c.send(bytes([int(1)]))
        c.close()
```

this question have already been asked many times but all the answers i could found is that i have to do " port forwarding " with out any code examples how to do it in some of the answers they say i should download application that will do the port forwarding to me but i don't know how to use it then in my python code ?

Answer (score 1):

Port forwarding is something you do at the router level. For example if the two computers you are trying to connect are behind two different WiFi routers at two different homes then you need to set both WiFi routers in both locations to forward port 10000 (the one you're using) to forward to the internal IP of the computer where your code is running.

Your WiFi router has a public IP (what you're probably using now) and your computers running your python code have local IPs internal to the network that are assigned by the WiFi routers. Port forwarding takes traffic going to the public IP of a router and forwards it internally in the local network to the computer at some local IP that runs your program.

In other words this is not something you will do in your code — this is something you will do in your router's software.

Answer (score 0):

If you are feeling ambitious you can follow this tutorial that removes the need to configure your devices for port forwarding. Assuming you have uPNP capable routers.

https://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2016/07/05/exploring-upnp-with-python/

And there may even be a module that takes all the leg work out.(not checked how it works)

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/UPnP/1.3

Comment: i couldn't download upnp i have been trying for days when i try to download it it say   "UPnP-1.3-py27-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."

Comment: I expect you are using python3.x? Have you tried under python2.7 ?

Comment: i am using python 3.6 and i didn't try it under python 2.7 i would try it now

Comment: I believe that .whl file is just zip. You can download the .whl and extract the relevant .py file. Then insert this into your code base. Modify as required for python 3.6.